# Convert date MongoDB / Javascript, but Nan

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, nan

I have a little problem with a date conversion in javascript.
I have a date format like this one `Wed Mar 09 10:32:14 CET 2016` from a Mongo database. When I want to get the month for example, I do this:

```
d=new Date('Wed Mar 09 10:32:14 CET 2016');
alert(d.getMonth());
```

But It does not work (`NaN` in the alert).
I know that a format like `Wed Mar 09 2016 10:32:14 GMT` will work, but the Database returns me `Wed Mar 09 10:32:14 CET 2016`.

I want to avoid the date format transformation.

Comment: `new Date('Wed Mar 09 10:32:14 CET 2016'.replace("CET ", ""))`

Comment: Did you read the docs for the `Date` constructor?

Comment: Yeah, thx, I found it :) Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the format `"Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT"`, the Date constructor allow use date as String but with the format specified before, the Date constructor use the `Date.parse` to parse the string to date, read further details about the [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). Store the date into mongodb in timestamps.